# Read memory block in C

Tags: c, pointers, memcpy, void-pointers

I have an assignment where I need to read from and write to a memory block (pre-allocated), to do so, I need to implement two functions:

```
memory_read(base,offset,size);
memory_write(base,offset,size,buffer);
```

No problem so far, I successfully implemented the writing part. The problem is with the memory_read. I need it to return a chunk of data (perhaps void*), then I can cast it to whatever I am expecting outside and use it.

Just as an example. Let's say I have written a serialised structure to that memory. I would like to do something like this

```
void *variable;
variable = memory_read(pointer_to_where_it_is,offset,sizeof(some_structure);
(some_structure) variable // and use it for something
```

And this is what memory_read does

```
void *memory_read(void *base, int offset, int size){
    void *buffer;
    buffer = malloc(size);
    memcpy(&buffer,base+offset,size);
    return buffer;
}
```

Of course, since buffer lives in the function stack, I lose reference to it on return.

Any idea on how to do it? I am not allowed to modify the function parameters by the teacher, otherwise I would have passed &variable as a parameter.

Thanks!

Comment: You lose reference to the pointer itself, but you already have the address returning from the function.

Comment: actually you are allocating memory from the heap and returning the pointer to that allocated memory within function `memory_read()` so that looks to be fine to me.  but do not use the address of operator withe the `memcpy()` function just pass the buffer variable containing the pointer directly,.

Comment: `memcpy(&buffer,base+offset,size);` : `&buffer` --> `buffer`, BTW `base+offset` is UB. (it is gcc extention)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY UB? Is it just *illegal code* in standard C? standard allows it compiled?

Comment: @ikh yes, Pointer arithmetic to `void *` is invalid in the standard. try gcc with option of `-pedantic`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this line:

```
memcpy(&buffer,base+offset,size);
```

the problem is that you are trying to copy a block of memory into a stack-allocated-variable `buffer` instead of the heap-allocated block of memory that this variable is pointing to. The fix is to remove the `&`:

```
memcpy(buffer, base+offset, size);
```

Otherwise your code is fine.

**UPDATE**: Don't forget to `free()` the returned buffer so the allocated memory doesn't "leak" :)